# SwiftUI: Animate changes in List without animating content changes

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos, swiftui-list

I have a simple app in SwiftUI that shows a `List`, and each item is a `VStack` with two `Text` elements:

```
var body: some View {
    List(elements) { item in
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item)) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.name) 
                Text(self.distanceString(for: item.distance))
            }
        }
    }
    .animation(.default)
}
```

The `.animate()` is in there because I want to animate changes to the list when the `elements` array changes. Unfortunately, SwiftUI also animates any changes to content, leading to weird behaviour. For example, the second `Text` in each item updates quite frequently, and an update will now shortly show the label truncated (with `...` at the end) before updating to the new content.

So how can I prevent this weird behaviour when I update the list's content, but keep animations when the elements in the list change?

In case it's relevant, I'm creating a watchOS app.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following should disable animations for row internals

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text(item.name) 
    Text(self.distanceString(for: item.distance))
}
.animation(nil)
```

Comment: I'm using an `List` within an `ForEach` and the sentence `.animation(nil)` doesn't work for   rows

Comment: `animation(_:)` is deprecated in iOS 15 in favour of `animation(_:value:)`, so `.animation(nil, value: 0)` seems to behave the same as `.animation(nil)`!

Answer (score 13):

The answer by @Asperi fixed the issue I was having also (Upvoted his answer as always).

I had an issue where I was animating the whole screen in using the below:     `AnyTransition.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .bottom), removal: .move(edge: .top))`

And all the Text() and Button() sub views where also animating in weird and not so wonderful ways. I used animation(nil) to fix the issue after seeing Asperi's answer. However the issue was that my Buttons no longer animated on selection, along with other animations I wanted.

So I added a new State variable to turn on and off the animations of the VStack. They are off by default and after the view has been animated on screen I enable them after a small delay:

```
struct QuestionView : View {
    @State private var allowAnimations : Bool = false

    var body : some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 6.0) {
            Text("Some Text")

            Button(action: {}, label:Text("A Button")
        }
        .animation(self.allowAnimations ? .default : nil)
        .onAppear() {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4) {
                self.allowAnimations = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just adding this for anyone who has a similar issue to me and needed to build on Asperi's excellent answer.

Comment: The .animation(:value:) call allows you to tie an animation only to a value change, rather than to disable the view for magic seconds.

Comment: Just discovered this one recently too @Beginner Don't tell everyone though as it detracts from my excellent answer above ;-)

Comment: Conspiracy: Upvote the answer and comment and everyone wins and learns. hehe... The .default though is good to know as a tool to stop a repeating animation.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Brett for the delay solution. My code needed it in several places, so I wrapped it up in a ViewModifier.

Just add **.delayedAnimation()** to your view.

You can pass parameters for defaults other than one second and the default animation.

```
import SwiftUI

struct DelayedAnimation: ViewModifier {
  var delay: Double
  var animation: Animation

  @State private var animating = false

  func delayAnimation() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
      self.animating = true
    }
  }

  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .animation(animating ? animation : nil)
      .onAppear(perform: delayAnimation)
  }
}

extension View {
  func delayedAnimation(delay: Double = 1.0, animation: Animation = .default) -> some View {
    self.modifier(DelayedAnimation(delay: delay, animation: animation))
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice one Jim!  

Answer (score 0):

In my case any of the above resulted in strange behaviours. The solution was to **animate the action that triggered the change in the elements array** instead of the list. For example:

```swift
@State private var sortOrderAscending = true

// Your list of elements with some sorting/filtering that depends on a state
// In this case depends on sortOrderAscending
var elements: [ElementType] {
    let sortedElements = Model.elements
    if (sortOrderAscending) {
        return sortedElements.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
    } else {
        return sortedElements.sorted { $0.name > $1.name }
    }
}

var body: some View {

    // Your button or whatever that triggers the sorting/filtering
    // Here is where we use withAnimation
    Button("Sort by name") {
        withAnimation {
            sortOrderAscending.toggle()
        }
    }

    List(elements) { item in
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item)) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.name) 
            }
        }
    }

}
```